# visitor counter

Tags: php, mysql, session, visitor-pattern

I have the below code its insert when user open the page and when refresh it,,,
I want to update visit table set leaveTime=$time when user leave the page by click any link inside the page which move to another page or click X or press ALT+F4 ......
here is my Attempt:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["visits"]))
    $_SESSION["visits"] = 0;
    $_SESSION["visits"] = $_SESSION["visits"] + 1;
if ($_SESSION["visits"] > 1){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO najd_visit( visit_userId, visit_staticId, visit_page, visit_enterTime,visit_refreshTime)VALUES ('$userId', '$Sid', '$title','$Stime' ,'$date') ");
    echo "You hit the refresh button!";}else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO najd_visit( visit_userId, visit_staticId, visit_page, visit_enterTime)VALUES ('$userId', '$Sid', '$title', '$date') ");
    echo "This is my site".$_SESSION["visits"];
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an existing service for this. I'm using [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/147983) as I like their real time stuff. [Google](http://www.google.com/analytics) is also used a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to register a user leaving the page. You could make an estimate based on the user's activity, but that's about it.

What you can do, however, is detect where the user came from. If the user starts at index.php at 1:00 and arrives at page2.php at 1:02, you can check the $_SERVER-superglobal to detect the user came from index.php and update that specific statistic.

But apart from all that, it's not really interesting to know when a user leaves your page.

Comment: how I can do that ??
I want to know when user open the page and when close it , and how long stay in it ??

Answer (score 2):

PHP can't detect when a visitor leaves your site.

You can, however, use JavaScript to detect a page `unload` event and then quickly make an AJAX request to record the departure ... this won't always work since network latency could cause your script to be "skipped" as the browser starts loading the next page.

To detect site departures from links on your own page, you could let all your links go to a small redirect script on your server; this records that the visitor left for another site.

In all other cases, you just have to assume that after 5 minutes or so the last page visited was the "departure page".

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create only visit counter refer this tutorial its perfect for you
http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-a-simple-pageviews-counter-using-php-and-mysql.php

first you have to create database

```
CREATE TABLE `pageview` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`page` text NOT NULL,
`userip` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

// totalview

```
CREATE TABLE `totalview` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`page` text NOT NULL,
`totalvisit` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the update the table whenever new visitor visits the web page

```
$user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$check_ip = mysql_query("select userip from pageview where page='yourpage' and userip='$user_ip'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check_ip)>=1)
{

}
else
{
  $insertview = mysql_query("insert into pageview values('','yourpage','$user_ip')");

  $updateview = mysql_query("update totalview set totalvisit = totalvisit+1 where page='yourpage' ");
}
```

and thats all

Comment: The link, suggests the code has been updated in 2020.  The mysql functions have been removed since version 7. So this code is no longer applicable.

Comment: This code uses the users IP as an identifier.  And tallies repeat visits in the totals table.  No time stamps are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

To check when a user left you can do this.

### On the client side

Do an ajax-request to http://www.yousite.com/update_user.php?userID=*user_id* every 10 secondes.

This script will update a row on your mysql database, it should look something like.

```
UPDATE online_user SET last_check=NOW() WHERE user_id=$_GET['userID']
```

### On the server side

> Launch a cron every minutes. It will check witch users didn't update their rows ( let's take 20 seconds to be safe)

```
SELECT user_id FROM online_user WHERE last_check <= *NOW() - 20 seconds*
```

Then you can edit rows where-ever you want saying the user corresponding to the user_id left between his 'last_check' and +10 seconds, you can do a request every 1 or 2 seconds if you need to be precise